# Jetty client and PATCH method

Tags: eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Is it possible to execute PATCH method with jetty client?
I am using Jetty 9.3.3 and the PATCH method is not defined in the enum HttpMethod.

I also checked the [api of Jetty 9.3.10](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.10.v20160621/apidocs/) and I did not find the PATCH method in the enum HttpMethod.

if it is not supported, how can I extend the Jetty code to be able to use it?
I only needed it in the client side (Jetty client need to be able to send Patch request).

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use the `PATCH` verb with the Jetty client.

The value in the `HttpMethod` enum is absent, but the recommendation is to pass `PATCH` as a string to the [`method()` API in the `Request`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.10.v20160621/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/api/Request.html#method-java.lang.String-).

[Support was added in this commit](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/0f702624a3011e3e1a953a4f0df468537caccd0d).

Comment: okey thanks, is there any intention that the PATCH will be added to the enum?

Comment: Link is dead to 'method() API in the Request'