# PATCH method in Jetty Client

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to update a json fragment using an HTTP PATCH call through Jetty. I've found that PATCH is not in the enumeration of the HttpClient class.

Another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096140/jetty-client-and-patch-method) asks the same question, but the link to the method() function is now a 404 and I cannot find method() in the Jetty source for HttpClient.

Does anybody have either working examples or an updated link to the method() function?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`method(String)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/api/Request.html#method-java.lang.String-) found in the `Request` object.

```java
Request request = client.newRequest("localhost", 8080)
            .method("PATCH")
            .path("/uri")
            .version(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

 ContentResponse response = request.send();
 Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
```